# How can I set cookie from my nestJs backend app to browser

Tags: authentication, cookies, nestjs, token

I want to set cookies in the browser in my NestJs service but it's not working.
this is my interceptor that setting cookies:

```
type Res = {
  token?: string
  refresh_token?: string
}

@Injectable()
export class CookieAttacherInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse<Response>()

return next
  .handle()
  .pipe(
    map((res: Res) => {
      if (res && (res.token || res.refresh_token)) {
        const auth = {
          token: res.token,
          refresh_token: res.refresh_token
        }
        response.cookie('auth-cookie', auth, {
          httpOnly: true,
          expires: new Date(Date.now() + 100 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
          sameSite: 'none',
          domain: process.env.COOKIE_DOMAIN ||'',
          secure: true,
          
        })
      }
      const { token, refresh_token, ...result } = res
      return result
    })
  )


}

}
```

and this is my login controller:

```
@Post('/login')
  @UseInterceptors(CookieAttacherInterceptor)
  async loginWithPassword(
    @Body() loginDto: LoginDto,
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) response: Response
  ) {
    const { statusCode, data } = await this.authService.loginWithPassword(loginDto)
    response.status(statusCode)
    return data
  }
```

and this my cors configurations:

```
app.enableCors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: '*',
    methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE']
  })
```

when I test it via Postman everything works correctly but we haven't access cookies from the browser.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the browser request look like?

Comment: did u set withCredential: true at the front end?

Comment: is your domain variable set? and if it is, it has to be a valid one - in your case should have the following value `.netlify.app` (notice the beginning dot)

Comment: Thanks a lot
The problem was resolved by setting withCredential in the front end but I'm curious to know how front-end devs should test their changes locally because the back-end API domain is different